# В форме первое поле вбивается номер, отправляется по APi, возвращает ответ смс код, но это не безопасно, где код хранить для проверки во втором поле

Tags: php, ajax, api

На сайте есть форма, в поле вбивается номер телефона, срабатывает аякс который по API отправляет номер телефона, API возвращает смс код в ответе, как его безопасно в следующем поле проверять? Есть ли хранилище где можно безопасно хранить код, для последующей проверки во втором поле? Или нужно записывать в БД сайта, а затем проверять по сессии? Как это вообще работает, штука распространена

Comment: проверять нужно конечно на сервере

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм примерно такой (все происходит в течение одного ajax-запроса):

1. Форма отправляет данные на сайт.
2. Сайт делает запрос к API, получает ответ и проверяет.
3. Сайт возвращает результат проверки посетителю.

Comment: сайт делает запрос по API и API присылает ответ, в виде кода ,  сайт возвращает посетителю ответ в  открытом виде,  как сделать закрытым, чтобы посетитель во втором поле  ввел код, и этот код проверяется на код который пришёл с акса